# Converting Currency Symbol to Currency Code: SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two separate data sources which has a column currency,

One has `Currency` present as `USD`
Another One has `$` present as data.

Is there a way to convert the symbol to USD ?

Also what if we have `multiple currencies, for eg:  euro, CAD`

Comment: It's always good to have lookup tables for things like this. Then you'd have an entry for 'USD' = 'US Dollars', but none for '$', so with a proper foreign key constraint the '$' could not be used in the currency column of your table.

Comment: As to the question: If you want to update your table, use `UPDATE`. If you want to update rows with currency = '$', then use `WHERE currency = '$'`. If you want to set these to 'USD', use `SET currency = 'USD'. Combined: `update mytable set currency = 'USD' where currency = '$'`. This is so simple, I wonder why you had problems finding this solution.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i don't know in future what currency will come in source , i need a generalised solution.

Comment: Are you saying that you have some _text_ data that could contain currency symbols and you want to convert it to currency code?

Comment: This is where a currency table as mentioned comes into play. Suddenly some person or process tries to insert '₼', but that fails, because this is a (yet) unknown currency. Then you agree that you want to allow this currency. You insert a row into the currency table with ISO code = 'AZN' and tell them they must use the ISO code instead of the currency symbol. Attention: You don't want to magically convert symbols into ISO codes, because the symbols don't uniquely identify a currency. The $ for instance is used for many currencies (US dollars, Australian dollars, Argentinian pesos, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a lookup table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE currencies (
  country_code  VARCHAR2(3),
  currency_code VARCHAR2(3), 
  name          VARCHAR2(50),
  symbol        VARCHAR2(5)
);

INSERT INTO currencies (country_code, currency_code, name, symbol)
SELECT 'USA', 'USD', 'US Dollar', '$' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'EU',  'EUR', 'Euro',      '€' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GBR', 'GBP', 'GB Pound',  '£' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'JPN', 'JPY', 'Yen',       '¥' FROM DUAL;
```

Then you can join your data source to the lookup table and select the currency code value rather than the symbol:

```sql
SELECT d.col1,
       d.col2,
       d.col3,
       c.currency_code
FROM   data_source1 d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN currencies c
       ON (d.currency = c.symbol);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using `CASE` or `DECODE`, e.g.

```
SQL> with test (currency) as
  2    (select 'USD' from dual union all
  3     select '$'   from dual
  4    )
  5  select currency,
  6         --
  7         case when currency = '$' then 'USD'
  8              else currency
  9         end new_currency_1,
 10         --
 11         decode(currency, '$', 'USD', currency) new_currency_2
 12  from test;

CURRENCY             NEW_CURRENCY_1       NEW_CURRENCY_2
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
USD                  USD                  USD
$                    USD                  USD

SQL>
```